# Javascript print function not printing the form elemnt changes

Tags: javascript, forms, printing

I have a HTML form similar to below :

```
    <div id="print">
        <h2>I am header</h2>
        Name : <input type="text" />
        College : B Borooah College
        <select>
            <option>Student</option>
            <option>Staff</option>
        </select>  
     <div>
<input type="button" value="PRINT" onclick="PrintContent()" />
```

And a `javascript` function to print the contents withing `#print` :

```
function PrintContent() 
{

    var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('print');
    var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');


    WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
    WindowObject.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
    WindowObject.document.writeln('</head><body>')

    WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);

    WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');

    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close();
}
```

When I click on `print` button, it prints the default form, not the form where I have added the `name` feld or changed the `select drop down`. How can I able to print the values I have entered/changed ?

Comment: pass also the values to the form, and pre-fill the form before calling the `window.print()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, maybe this helps:

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/Sample/

Cheers